# unable to copy database using SQLiteAssetHelper class

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-assets

I am extending `SQLiteAssetHelper` class to use my pre-populated database from assets folder but my app crashed and gave an error saying `Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database`.

**When I checked in `ddms`, there was no databases folder or my `db` file in `data/data/com.sqlitetospinner1/`. So to just test, I created a folder named `databases` and pushed the db file into it. After this the app started to work perfectly.**

It means my `AssetsHelper` class failed to copy database.

`AssetsHelper` class:-

```
public class AssetsHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb.sqlite";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public AssetsHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}


public List<String> getAllColleges(){
    List<String> colleges = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM colleges_list ORDER BY Organization_Name";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            colleges.add(cursor.getString(1));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // closing connection
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // returning colleges
    return colleges;
}
```

`LogCat:-`

```
 08-25 08:41:21.927: W/SQLiteAssetHelper(27504): copying database from assets...
    08-25 08:41:22.107: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27504): Couldn't open mydb.sqlite for writing (will try read-only):
    08-25 08:41:22.107: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27504): com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper$SQLiteAssetException: Missing databases/mydb.sqlite file (or .zip, .gz archive) in assets, or target folder not writable
    08-25 08:41:22.107: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27504):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
    08-25 08:41:22.107: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27504):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:316)
    08-25 08:41:22.107: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27504):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:290)
    08-25 08:41:22.107: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27504):     at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.copyDatabaseFromAssets(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:436)
    08-25 08:41:22.107: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27504):     at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.createOrOpenDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:400)
    08-25 08:41:22.107: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27504):     at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:176)
    08-25 08:41:22.107: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27504):     at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:254)
    08-25 08:41:22.107: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27504):     at com.crm.AssetsHelper.getAllColleges(AssetsHelper.java:38)
08-25 08:41:22.107: E/SQLiteAssetHelper(27504):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-25 08:41:22.117: E/SQLiteLog(27504): (14) cannot open file at line 30191 of [00bb9c9ce4]
08-25 08:41:22.117: E/SQLiteLog(27504): (14) os_unix.c:30191: (2) open(/data/data/com.sqlitetospinner1/databases/mydb.sqlite) - 
08-25 08:41:22.167: E/SQLiteDatabase(27504): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.sqlitetospinner1/databases/mydb.sqlite'.
08-25 08:41:22.167: E/SQLiteDatabase(27504): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
08-25 08:41:22.167: E/SQLiteDatabase(27504):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
08-25 08:41:22.167: E/SQLiteDatabase(27504):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
08-25 08:41:22.167: E/SQLiteDatabase(27504):    at com.crm.AssetsHelper.getAllColleges(AssetsHelper.java:38)
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace. Also, is your pre-packaged database in the right spot in `assets/`? Are there other noteworthy messages in LogCat?

Comment: @CommonsWare added `LogCat`

Comment: `Missing databases/mydb.sqlite file (or .zip, .gz archive) in assets, or target folder not writable` Do you have the database file in your `assets/databases` folder?

Comment: @laalto no, in `assets` folder only

Comment: adding to `databases` folder also didn't helped

Comment: Uninstall your app so you start with clean internal storage. Then run your again. If it crashes, post the new stack trace, as either it is different, or you do not have `mydb.sqlite` in `assets/databases/` within your project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> > `Missing databases/mydb.sqlite file (or .zip, .gz archive) in assets, or target folder not writable`
> >
> > Do you have the database file in your `assets/databases` folder?
>
> no, in assets folder only

`SQLiteAssetHelper` expects to find the prepopulated database file in `databases` folder under  `assets`.

Comment: added in `databases` folder but nothing changed still same error

Comment: Rebuild and reinstall the app, too, and make sure its `assets/databases/mydb.sqlite` (or an archive with the same prefix)

Comment: I am not able to resolve this.. I have put .zip file at correct path only

Answer (score 0):

> Right click on your database file in the **Package Explorer**,
>
> & click on the Properties.
>
> inside the **Resource** Tab make sure the "**Write**" Permission is Checked for the "**Owner**" and "**Read**" Permission is Checked for all the "**Users**".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the db file under assets\databases folder in your app, in the main folder.

Also make sure you have specified the correct database name, so if your file name is data.db, your database name should be data.db.

```
public class MyHelperDatabase extends com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data.db";
```

Or if you are using Room:

```
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;

    @VisibleForTesting
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data.db";
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **Error**: "Missing databases/EDMTQuiz2019.db file".
2. **Cause**: my folder was not named properly...
   It was assets/database,
   Instead of assets/databases
3. **Solution**: I solved mine by refactoring/renaming the folder 
   "database" to "databases"
4. **Summary**: the new right path is assets/databases  (the .db file is in the database folder)