# Exception while using SQLiteAssetHelper class

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-7.0-nougat, android-assets

I am trying to use [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) to copy my pre-populated db into android app. I have Android-7 on my device(Nvidia Shield & Motorola Phone). From Settings->App->MyApp I have enabled **Calender**, **Location** & **Storage** permissions

I have following permission in Manifest file as well

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

When I keep my db in `assets/databases/databases` folder, I get following exception:

> Caused by: com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper$SQLiteAssetException: Unable to write /data/user/0/com.funcheap.funmapsf/databases/databases/MySFfuncheapDatabase.db to data

When I keep my db in `assets/databases` folder, I get following exception:

> Caused by: com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper$SQLiteAssetException: Missing databases/databases/MySFfuncheapDatabase.db file (or .zip, .gz archive) in assets, or target folder not writable

Unfortunately, this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25486042/unable-to-copy-database-using-sqliteassethelper-class) doesnt help me

Comment: You don't need that permission to write to your app's internal storage area (`/data/.../<your app>/...`). That's used only for external storage (usually `/storage/emulated/0/...`)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], in particular showing your `SQLiteAssetHelper` subclass. I think your problem is in the database name that you are providing to the `SQLiteAssetHelper` constructor. See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/Database/ConstantsAssets-AndroidStudio) for how to use `SQLiteAssetHelper`.

Comment: Could it be due to the path containing **databases** directory twice? i.e. should it be using  `/data/user/0/com.funcheap.funmapsf/databases/MySFfuncheapDatabase.db` instead of `/data/user/0/com.funcheap.funmapsf/databases/databases/MySFfuncheapDatabase.db`?

Answer (score 0):

As @miket said if you reference the internal path Android will use that reference I had this issue and this was my very sloppy test code NOTE commented out call

```
public void getINTERNAL(){
    Context context = this;
    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
    String NT = String.valueOf(file);
    THE_PATH = NT+"/";
    System.out.println("INTERNAL PATH =========> "+THE_PATH);
}


public void getAvailable(){

    //getINTERNAL();

    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) && (!state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY))) {

        File removable = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(this, null)[1];
        THE_PATH = String.valueOf(removable);
        if(THE_PATH.length() > 4) {
            //THE_PATH = THE_PATH.substring(0, THE_PATH.length() - 5);
            THE_PATH = THE_PATH + "/Documents/";
            System.out.println("new path ====> "+THE_PATH);
        }
        System.out.println("EXTERNAL PATH ====> " + THE_PATH);
        System.out.println("Internal Path used if EXTERNAL PATH = NULL ");
        //getINTERNAL(); DO NOT CALL HERE YOU WILL CHANGE THE_PATH TO internal
        // no need to set THE_PATH for internal storage it will default on its own
        // WHY DOES THIS HAPPEN THE_PATH variable is PUBLIC STATIC hence it is GLOBAL
    }
}
```